# Fancybox 2 How to add custom column on the side of the picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

I am building a gallery and started playing with fancyBox 2. It is pretty cool, I only have one problem. I want to split fancyBox into two columns, one for image and another one for comments. I want the picture to be on the left side, and comments to be on the right.

I have tried using bootstrap rows/columns but it does not seem to work.
This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    tpl: {
      image : '<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-9"><img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" /></div><div class="col-lg-3">Comments will go here</div></div></div>',
    }
  });
});
```

I have also tried playing with other fancyBox template sections such as wrap. I tried to adding columns there but I did not achieve what I wanted.

I have also tried loading the fancyBox using ajax like this:

```
href : "test.php",
type : 'ajax',
ajax: {
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        temp: "tada"
    }
},
```

And this is a content of php file:

```
$template = "";
$template .= '<div class="container">';
$template .= '<div class="row">';
$template .= '<div class="col-lg-9">';
$template .= '<img class="fancybox-image img-responsive" src="http://image.com/theimage.jpg">';
$template .= '</div>';
$template .= '<div class="col-lg-3">';
$template .= 'Comments go here';
$template .= '</div>';
$template .= '</div>';
$template .= '<div>';
echo $template;
```

But this does not resize the box properly - here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have been playing with this all day and searched everywhere but did not found any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably avoid bootstraps on this one, except for maybe the "img-responsive" tag. This will give the functionality I believe you are after.

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .fancyBox{
  position: inherit;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 .images{
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
 }
 .comment{
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <title>Fancy Box</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="fancyBox">
 <div class="images">
 </div><div class="comment"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me as I need the image and comments section to display in the fancybox window